# object array to NSMutable array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an array of Objects.Object contains three values, id,name,value.I want to parse name from this object array and want to create a different array of names only....Can anyone help Plz.....

```
int i; 
NSInteger *namesCount=[eCategories count]; //eCategories is an object array 
SubCategories *subCategoriesList=[[SubCategories alloc] init];
//SubCategories is a NSObject class containing cat_name,cat_id,cat_value. 
NSMutableArray *nameArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
for(i=0;i<namesCount;i++)
{ 
    subCategoriesList=[eCategories objectAtIndex:i]; 
    nameArray=subCategoriesList.cat_name; 
}
```

Comment: int i;
    NSInteger *namesCount=[eCategories count];
    SubCategories *subCategoriesList=[[SubCategories alloc] init];//NSObject class containing cat_name,cat_id,cat_value.
    NSMutableArray *nameArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(i=0;i<namesCount;i++){
        subCategoriesList=[eCategories objectAtIndex:i];
        nameArray=subCategoriesList.cat_name;
    }  I am making some mistake that i knw......i am a begineer tryng to learn Objective c.This is the code..

Comment: You should edit your answer rather than put the code in a comment where it is totally unreadable.  I've done it for you this time :)

Answer (score 1):

NSArray has a method [-valueForKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ) which does exactly what you want in one message

> Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.

```
NSArray* nameArray = [eCategories valueForKey: @"cat_name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
[objects valueForKeyPath: @"@distinctUnionOfArrays.name"]
```

Unless, of course, the objects inside the array are not NSDictionaries with "name" as the key for the names. You're not telling us enough.

Answer (score -1):

int i;

NSInteger *namesCount=[eCategories count]; //eCategories is an object array

SubCategories *subCategoriesList=[[SubCategories alloc] init];

//SubCategories is a NSObject class containing cat_name,cat_id,cat_value.

NSMutableArray *nameArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(i=0;i

[nameArray addobject:subCategoriesList.cat_name];
}